# Provide multiple paths in the azure function path bindings for storage

Tags: azure-functions

I am using azure function to be called when there is a file copied in my ADLS gen2 storage account. There are roughly 10 containers in the ADLS gen2 storage and I would like to call this function app only when a file is copied to either 2 of the containers, later I will be increase it to more. My container names are like abc, def.... and inside them files are copied.

In my azure function I have input bindings like

```
{
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "abc/{name}.{csv}",
      "connection": "storage account"
}
```

How can I add def to the input path, Is multiple path supported here. I would like to call the same function when a file is copied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the blob trigger (which polls the storage account), you can use the [Event Grid Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid) which is a recommended alternative in the [blob storage trigger doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp) itself.

With this, you will have a single Event Grid triggered function which reacts to events coming from Event Grid. Also, you can [filter events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-filtering) based on your requirement.

Another approach would be to change the path to something like this `{path}/{name}.{csv}`. With this, your function will get invoked for each file and in your code, check the path.

Also, note that using `.{csv}` will create a binding for the extension to a variable named `csv`. If the intention is to just trigger on `.csv` files, then just use it without the braces.